# Python: Sum of certain values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {'A': 71.07884,
    'B': 110
    'C': 103.14484,
    'D': 115.08864,
    'E': 129.11552,
    'F': 147.1766,
   }

name = "ABC"

for character in name:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key == character:
            print(value)
```

I have a dictionary dict and a string name. Now I want to sum the values of dict that are equals with characters of the string name.

With my solution I just get the values 
71.07884,
110,
103.14484 but how I can sum this values.

If I try print(sum(value)) I get this: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

I'm new in python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error because the `value` changes as per its iterator. Inorder to find the sum you need to store and add the values to another variable and then call `sum()` or you could add it to a new variable.

What the `sum()` does is take a list and iterate through it. In your code what it is doing is passing the current value in the loop only so 1 value.

Example: Note (There are many ways to do this.)

```
name = "ABC"
sum = 0
for character in name:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key == character:
            print(value)
            sum = value + sum

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way - initialize an empty list first and then everytime you get the value in the loop, `append` it to the list. You'll get a list `[71.07884, 110, 103.14484]`, which you can then sum.

```
dict = {'A': 71.07884,
    'B': 110,
    'C': 103.14484,
    'D': 115.08864,
    'E': 129.11552,
    'F': 147.1766,
   }

name = "ABC"
values = []
for character in name:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key == character:
            values.append(value)
sum(values)
```

Output:

```
sum(values)
Out[6]: 284.22368
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
mydict = {'A': 71.07884,
    'B': 110,
    'C': 103.14484,
    'D': 115.08864,
    'E': 129.11552,
    'F': 147.1766,
   }

name = "ABC"

sum(value for key, value in mydict.items() if key in name)

# 284.22368
```

Note that I renamed your dictionary to `mydict`, as `dict` is a Python builtin function, which you shouldn't use as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
list_name = "ADF"    
sum([value for key, value in dict.items() if key in list_name])
```

Comment: No need  to make a list when using `sum`: `sum(value for key, value in dict.items() if key in list_name)`